# jExpand not for the whole table; just for some lines

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, expand

I'm trying to use jExpand (http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/expand-table-rows-with-jquery-jexpand-plugin/) just for some lines of my table, not the every lines !

You can see here on the demo link :

http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/wp-content/uploads/examples/expandable-rows/

You can expand every line (every country) to get more informations.

I my case I want to make expandable just some lines not every lines.

For example I want to make expandable just "United Kingdom" and "India" lines.

How i need to do ?

I tried to delete  `div class="arrow"></div>` but we still can expand the line :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `class` to the rows that you don't want to expand and ignore them in the script.
In my example I added the class `.nope`.

```
$("#report tr:odd:not(.nope)").addClass("master");
$("#report tr:not(.master, .nope)").hide();
$("#report tr:first-child").show();
$("#report tr.master").click(function(){
    $(this).next("tr").toggle();
    $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
});
```

[TEST IT HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/ceRnP/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove class "odd" from the rows that you don't want to be extended.
The framework might use that name for its processing. If the framework is the one which attributes that class to the rows, then you need to check the frameworks options...